# How to create two different Apps (Play Store / Amazon Store) from same Eclipse project?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, amazon-appstore

I would like to offer my Android 4+ app both in the Play Store and in the Amazon Market. I found several questions here on SO dealing with the question how to integrate both stores in the same APK. This seems to be quite difficult since there is not reliable why to check wether the app was download from store A or B, but if it was loaded from B all links to the store, reviews, etc. have to point back to B, etc...

Thus both stores in the same APK is not what I am looking for. I would like to create two different APKs, one for each store. Additional bonus: The APKs will be smaller since each will only contain the libs it really needs. How can this be done?

In Xcode/iOS I would simply create two different targets, each with its own set of libs and configurations. How can this be done in Eclipse? There is only one AppManifest and the "File/Export/Export Android Application" option always uses the same configuration to create the same APK.

What can I do to create two different app version from the same Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the answer you're looking for but it's the reality.

Eclipse + ADT is not a very flexible way of building apps and to do what you're asking for you'll need a fairly big amount of ANT scripting (I saw it before in a banking app that build different .apks for each of it's brands). But it's probably even more complex than building everything into one apk.

On the other hand, if you're willing to migrate your project to AndroidStudio + Gradle, that is a way more flexible approach to software building and they have an "easy to use" concept of flavours, here is a snippet of the build.gradle of the app I work:

```
productFlavors {
    phone {
        resConfigs "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi", "nodpi"
        versionCode 100000 + project.ver.versionCode
    }
    phone_low_end {
        resConfigs "ldpi", "mdpi", "hdpi", "nodpi"
        versionCode 200000 + project.ver.versionCode
    }
    tablet {
        versionCode 300000 + project.ver.versionCode
    }
    unified {
        versionCode project.ver.versionCode
    }
}
sourceSets{
    unified{
        res {
            srcDir 'src/tablet/res'
        }
        assets{
            srcDirs 'src/phone/assets', 'src/tablet/assets'
        }

    }
}
```

and with that fairly small configuration the project is being built with different versionCode, with different assets. For your project you could easily integrate like this:

```
sourceSets{
    googleplay{
        src {
            srcDir 'src/googleplay/java/'
        }
    }
    amazon{
        src {
            srcDir 'src/amazon/java/'
        }
    }
}
```